# Sabel(PHP)のマイグレーションツールについて

Tags: php, linux

いにしえのPHPフレームワーク「Sabel」にて大変困っております。

マイグレーションツールを実行したいのですが、
以下のエラーが出て動かすことができません。。

```
-bash-4.1# pwd
/var/www/html/AppName/Sabel/bin
-bash-4.1# sakle Migration development head
-bash: sakle: command not found
-bash-4.1# sh sakle Migration development head
PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/AppName/Sabel/bin/config/INIT.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/AppName/Sabel/sabel/Sakle.php on line 8
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/AppName/Sabel/bin/config/INIT.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/AppName/Sabel/sabel/Sakle.php on line 8
```

上記のINIT.phpは元々存在しませんでした。
（生成する手順がある？）

ちなみに「Sabel」フレームワークですが、
チュートリアルやインストールマニュアルが現在はCloseされているため、
大変困っています。
　http://www.sabel.jp/doc
　http://www.sabel.jp/doc/install

有用なドキュメントをご存知でしたら、
共有していただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

※"他のFW使えば？"はナシでお願いします....

早期解決を望んでおりますので、同じ質問を[teratailにも投稿させていただきました](https://teratail.com/questions/130976)。。。

Comment: ご存知かもしれませんが、ご提示のリンクは Internet Archive に 2009 年時点のものが残っていました。 [www.sabel.jp/doc](https://web.archive.org/web/*/www.sabel.jp/doc) / [www.sabel.jp/doc/install](https://web.archive.org/web/*/www.sabel.jp/doc/install)

Comment: ありがとうございます。。。。　Internet Archiveを見る発想はありませんでした。非常に助かりました。

Comment: [sabel.php-framework.org のアーカイブ](https://web.archive.org/web/20100305133936/http://sabel.php-framework.org)からリンクされている[非公式ドキュメントのアーカイブ](https://web.archive.org/web/20100309004916/http://ebine.org:80/sabel/doc/index.html)を見つけたのですが、肝心のマイグレーションについてのページはアーカイブされていませんでした :(

Comment: バージョン 1.2Beta1 だと `INIT.php` 自体は `./generator/skeleton/en/config/INIT.php` に存在するので、この generator が関係していそうです。

Comment: そこまで調べていただけるなんて、、ありがとうございます。

Comment: generator...探ってみます。

Comment: どのバージョンの Sabel をお使いかは分かっているのでしょうか？

Comment: INIT.phpはこちらのパスにありました。　/var/www/html/AppName/config/INIT.php

Comment: Sabelのバージョンは不明です...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プロジェクトルートから実行することで、実行できました。

```
$ cd /var/www/html/AppName/
$ Sabel/bin/sakle Migration development head
```

Answer (score 1):

ひとつ上のディレクトリで、

```
bin/sakle Migration development head
```

これでできませんか?

Comment: 同じエラー(質問内容に記載)が出てしまいます。。

Comment: 対象のソースコードをどこかのprivate repositoryに上げてもらえれば調査できます…!

Comment: すみません、諸事情でソースのお見せすることが難しそうです。。